# well formed formulas?

Tags: logic

> which of the following expressions are well formed formulas?
>   $$\lnot(\lnot P\lor \lnot \lnot R)$$
>   $$\lnot(P,Q, \land R)$$
>   $$P \land \lnot P$$
>   $$(P \lor Q)(P \lor R)$$

To me they all seem like they are not well formed formulas:

The first has a double negative

The second has ambiguous commas

The third contradicts itself

And the fourth is ambiguous as to what happens to both the brackets

However the way the question is phrased makes me think that at least one, maybe two, of these statements must be well formed, am i right? or am i missing something?

Comment: Double negatives and contradictory formulas are perfectly well-formed. "Well-formed" just means *grammatically correct*, not efficiently-written or non-stupid.

Comment: okay thank you, that makes a lot of sense, the text book didn't explain it very much, could you write it as an answer please?

Comment: It *may* be the case that for some reason your textbook demands parentheses such as $\neg(\neg R)$ for double negation, but I highly doubt that; more likely, it *may* demand parentheses around conjugations, ie.e., $(P\land\neg P)$ instead of $P\land \neg P$. #1 and #3 look pretty ok, but for strict affirmative answers one would have to know the *precise* definition of wff used.

Comment: A [question by a different person](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008176/determining-which-of-the-following-expressions-are-well-formed-formulas) reveals that this is an exercise in _How to Prove It_ by Velleman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *possible* grammar for well-formed formulae:

$$ \begin{align}\langle \text S\rangle&::= \langle \text V\rangle\mid\neg\langle S\rangle\mid (\langle \text S\rangle\langle \text{op}\rangle\langle \text S\rangle)\\
\langle\text V\rangle&::= P\mid Q\mid R\\
\langle\text{op}\rangle&::=\land\mid \lor\mid \to
\end{align}$$
According to this grammar, *only* the first of the given four strings is a wff, using the following derivation:
$$\begin{matrix}\langle \text S\rangle\\
\neg&&&\langle \text S\rangle\\
\neg&(&\langle \text S\rangle&\langle \text {op}\rangle&\langle \text S\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg\langle \text S\rangle&\langle \text {op}\rangle&\langle \text S\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg\langle \text V\rangle&\langle \text {op}\rangle&\langle \text S\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg P&\langle \text {op}\rangle&\langle \text S\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg P& \lor&\langle \text S\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg P& \lor&\neg\langle \text S\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg P& \lor&\neg\neg\langle \text S\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg P& \lor&\neg\neg\langle \text V\rangle&)\\
\neg&(&\neg P& \lor&\neg\neg R&)
\end{matrix}
 $$

The second string is not a wff because the above grammar does not use "," at all -- but your text *may* use a grammar for wff that for example allows functions with more than one parameter and separate these with ",".

The third string is not a wff because any inroduction of "$\land$" necessarily also introduces "$($" and "$)$" -- but your text may employ a more complex grammar that manages to get rid of parentheses that look superfluous to the human reader (of all possibilities, I consider this the lest unlikely).

The fourth string is not wff because (as can be shown, if needed by structural induction) that "$)($" cannot occur as a substring in a wff -- but even here, your text *may* introduce juxtaposition as an alternative form of writing conjunction, for example.

Admittedly, all variants that I put into "your text may ..." are somewhat unlikely in a formal context.