# Determining which of the following expressions are well-formed formulas.

Tags: logic

just getting my start in proofs and had a little difficulty with the following problem in the book How to Prove it by Velleman.

Which of the following expressions are well-formed formulas?

$1. \neg(\neg P\vee \neg\neg R)\\
2. \neg(P,Q,\wedge R)\\
3. P\wedge \neg P\\
4. (P\vee Q)(P\vee R)$

I did some research here and found that this question was asked before here [well formed formulas?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333925/well-formed-formulas), but I didn't find the answer too satisfactory and it contradicted many of the independent solutions posted out there that don't justify their reasoning.

So I understand why 1 and 3 are well-formed formulas, and my reasoning for 2. not being a well-formed formula is that $\neg(P,Q,\wedge R) \iff \neg P, \neg Q, \neg\wedge R$, and it's that last part $\neg\wedge R$ that is nonsensical and leads the expression to not being a well-formed formula.

As for 4, my thoughts are that there needs to be conjunction or disjunction between the two statements for it to be a well-formed formula as it reads to me either P or Q either P or V, which sounds nonsensical to me without the "and" or "or".

Is my reasoning for arriving at these conclusions correct? Thanks.

Comment: The point of this exercise is to make sure you have understood the _particular details of the definition of "well-formed formula"_ given in that book (which may not be exactly the same as the definition of "well-formed formula" in the next textbook over). So you need to look at that particular definition -- and quote the definition in its entirety here if that doesn't clear up things for you.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this. So I will quote directly from the book: "The symbols ∧ and ∨ can only be
used between two statements, to form their conjunction or disjunction, and the
symbol ¬ can only be used before a statement, to negate it. This means that
certain strings of letters and symbols are simply meaningless. For example,
P¬∧ Q, P ∧/∨ Q, and P¬Q are all “ungrammatical” expressions in the
language of logic. “Grammatical” expressions, such as those in Examples 1.1.2
and 1.1.3, are sometimes called well-formed formulas or just formulas".

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the syntactic rules you are checking against.  They should have things like if $a$ is a wff then $\lnot a$ is a wff and if $a$ and $b$ are wffs then $(a \vee b)$ is a wff.  You justify something is a wff by citing the rules necessary to build it up.  $P\wedge \lnot P$ may well not be a wff because it does not have parentheses around it.  For $2$, you may not have any rules that involve a comma, so it cannot be well formed.  For $4$ you should not have any rules that result in neighboring parentheses in that configuration.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the answer. Looking back at the section in the chapter, there does not seem to be any rules regarding commas explicitly. But there was an earlier exercise that I did which did use the comma: "Analyze the logical forms of the following statements: 3 is a common divisor of 6, 9, and 15". Or perhaps the comma in the above context is valid only in English and not in logical form? Apologies, but I am not quite used to this level of ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, that exercise used the comma in English.  There are a number of ways of writing propositional logic.  "Well formed formula" means it is properly formed using the rules you have.  Often they require parentheses as I mentioned to avoid having $P \vee Q \wedge R$ be well formed because you don't know how to parse it.  Is it $(P \vee Q) \wedge R$ or $P \vee (Q \wedge R)?$  They then need to say "and anything you cannot form this way is not a well formed formula".

Comment: Got it. Thanks once again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your reasoning is correct but 2nd part makes no sense because negation operator requires a single operand and \neg\wedge R being nonsensical too. To be short and simple operators like ¬,∨ or ∧ require finite number of operands as per their definitions.